# Input masking ( thousand separator / decimal-us) using Knock out read & write options

Tags: regex, jquery-plugins, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I have a requirement of formating the decimal value to US dollar format (that is every decimal number should be appended with a $ symbol at the beginning & introduce comma after every 3 digits.

For example : 999999999 should be converted to $999,999,999.00 for display purpose while the original value should be retained as it is for further calculations.

```
        self.MonthlyAppliedEmployerContributionAmount = ko.observable(MonthlyAppliedEmployerContribution);

        self.MonthlyAppliedEmployerContributionAmountFormatted = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return '$' + parseFloat(self.MonthlyAppliedEmployerContributionAmount()).toFixed(2);
            },
            write: function (value) {
                // Strip out unwanted characters, parse as float, then write the raw data back to the underlying "price" observable
                value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
                self.MonthlyAppliedEmployerContributionAmount(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value); // Write to underlying storage
            }
        });
```

Here while reading the observable property, I am appending $ at the beginning & .toFixed(2) helped me to achieve to restrict 2 decimals.

But I m not sure how to introduce comma after every three digits.

NB : In the KO write method I am removing all the formatting that is introduced in the read meothod.

I dont want to use Jquery mask plugin as most of them are not directly from Jquery lib, but made by some third party, which might break at some point of time.

Appreciate an early response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression to insert thousand separators:

```
function addThousandSeparator(s) { 
  return s.replace(/(\d)(?:(?=\d+(?=[^\d.]))(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)|(?=\d+(?=\.))(?=(?:\d{3})+(?=\.)))/gm, '$1,');
}
```

If you need another thousand separator, replace the comma in `'$1,'` with your separator.

So you would have:

```
read: function () {
            return '$' + addThousandSeparator(parseFloat(self.MonthlyAppliedEmployerContributionAmount())
                         .toFixed(2));

        }
```

Comment: Thx for the quick response. Can you plz expalin what u meant by : If you need another thousand separator, replace the comma in '$1,' with your separator.

Comment: In France the thousand separator is a space (10 000 000), it seems you need a comma (10,000,000) but in case you need something else you can replace '$1,' with '$1[yourseparatorhere]' at the end of the `replace`

Comment: Excellent, It is working as expected :) Just trying to understand ur complex regular expression... What is the significance of /gm here & how '$1, ' is helping here to achieve our desired format?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand it all myself. I needed this for a project and searched quite a while for this one on the web. This said, I can answer your questions: /gm are flags to tell the regex where to look; $1 returns the first group. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/regularexpressionsyntax.htm

Comment: I can also tell you this regexp uses lookahead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the exiting localization libraries that will do the parsing and formattign for you. For example:

- [numerals.js](http://adamwdraper.github.io/Numeral-js/)
- [jQuery globalization plugin](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx)
- [Intl.js](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js)

These are some of the most popular, and will easily solve your problem.